# How to verify a python object is a datetime, not a date?

Tags: python, datetime

Since datetime is an instance of a date object, how do I determine that it's not in fact, a date?

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
today = date.today()
now = datetime.now()
if isinstance(now, date)   # returns True!
    today-now              # Fails, because it's not a date
```

This naturally returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to force the second operand to be a `date` so that the subtraction always works.

```
today - date(now.year, now.month, now.day)
```

This will work when `now` is either a `date` or a `datetime` object, or is in fact any type that quacks enough like them (i.e. has `year`, `month`, and `day` attributes that contain integers that specify a valid date).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `type()` to test for an explicit type, without allowing for subclasses:

```
if type(now) is date:
```

Alternatively, just catch the `TypeError`:

```
if isinstance(now, date):
    try:
        today - now
    except TypeError:
        # hrm, `now` is a subclass that is not supported
```

or explicitly exclude `datetime`:

```
if isinstance(now, date) and not isinstance(now, datetime):
```

or use a `.date()` method if available:

```
try:
    # support `datetime` objects too
    now = now.date()
except AttributeError:
    pass
today - now
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize the difference between type and isinstance!